# Hyperledger fabric: setting up development environment, "make peer" freezes

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to set up fabric hyperledger development environment in my Macboor air (OSX Yosemite, i5, 4GB Ram, 2013 model), following the [guide here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/dev-setup/devenv.md).

After I setup, I ssh into vagrant, and when I run "make peer" It freezes up my laptop (I waited more than an hour), and I have to reboot. Here is the posiotion where it freezes. Any Idea whats going wrong?

```js
vagrant@hyperledger-devenv:v0.2.0-b9eb696:~$ cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    vagrant@hyperledger-devenv:v0.2.0-b9eb696:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric$ make peer
    Building build/image/ccenv/bin/protoc-gen-go
    Unable to find image 'hyperledger/fabric-baseimage:x86_64-0.2.0' locally
    x86_64-0.2.0: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-baseimage
    6bbedd9b76a4: Already exists 
    fc19d60a83f1: Already exists 
    de413bb911fd: Already exists 
    2879a7ad3144: Already exists 
    668604fde02e: Already exists 
    a3ed95caeb02: Download complete 
    24f06c7667d6: Already exists 
    867f5c7a5d67: Extracting [=================================>                 ] 262.4 MB/393.2 MB
```

Comment: are you sure it freezes up the laptop and you cannot abort the process using `CTRL+C` ?

Comment: yes, completely unresponsive, ctrl+c dies not work.